# Failed to display images in listbox control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, listbox, datatemplate

I' trying to display an image along with some text as a listbox item - the text is displayed but the image is not.
Here's the datatemplate xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DT">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Image Source="C:\test1.png" Height="24" Width="24" />
<sdk:Label Content={Binding} />
</StackPanel>
<DataTemplate>

<ListBox x:Name="bla" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DT}">

</ListBox>
```

When I'm trying to display the same image outside the listbox it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include image in your project and use relative path:

```
<Image Source="test1.png" Height="24" Width="24" />
```

Comment: It works when I put the image under the same folder where the .xaml file resides. What's the appropriate syntax of referring to another folder within the same assembly?
i.e. the .xaml file is under Views folder and the image file is under Images folder...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use relative path rules. <Image Source="../Images/test1.png" Height="24" Width="24" />